# Visual Studio '15' Preview 5 installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, logfile

If I try to install Visual Studio '15' Preview 5, I get an Error and the following logfile:

```
2016-10-07T18:05:42 : Verbose : SetupEngine.Installer.InstallProduct reported error.  [channelId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Channels.Preview, productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise, installationPath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview', InvalidOperationException: No products are registered for instance '45ee4dcd-d923-4bcb-8a1a-539f6a4fba3c' at    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CommonExtensions.GetProduct(IInstance instance, Boolean installedOnly)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.GetAvailablePackages()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Initialize()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Load(IChannelProduct channelProduct, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service.CreateEngine(IChannelProduct channelProduct, String instanceId, TelemetryContext telemetryContext, String localeOverride, IMessageBus messageBus, IRestartManager restartManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallerService.InstallProductImpl(Product product, String installationPath, String setupExecutablePath, String setupExecutableArguments, TelemetryContext telemetryContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallerService.InstallProduct(Product product, String installationPath, String setupExecutablePath, String setupExecutableArguments, TelemetryContext telemetryContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)]
```

I get this Error with every configuration. I also tried to set the language to English cause my main language is not English.

Comment: I was getting this error is VS2017, and it turned out I just had to re-run `install` instead of `update` after using `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe" -f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. This worked for me:

To uninstall modern installs of Visual Studio "15" Previews 1-3:

```
Launch the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer from the start menu.
Uninstall Visual Studio from the installer.
From Add / Remove Programs (Windows 7) or Programs and Features (Windows 8.1 and 10), select Microsoft Visual Studio Installer and uninstall.
Delete %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\.
Delete the Visual Studio folder (normally under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview).
You should now be able to install Preview 5.
```

Don't worry that instructions are for previous preview versions

Source: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes#workaround

Comment: Where is the installer/setup exe/msi file located? Uninstallation failed but then the program was still removed "15" from the list of installed programs, so I need to locate the installer and try and run it - but I can't find it.

Comment: @BentRasmussen: there is no such. To remove VS "15" you must do it by hand just like I wrote. Then you will be able to install it again (unfortunatly). At this point you will be able to remove VS from system from VS "15" installer. Yep, that is strange.

Comment: This didn't work for me - possibly because the uninstall failed, but still removed the installer. Looks like it's in a semi-uninstalled state